# What is the proper handling of Mach number?

Tags: names

My question mainly concerns named numbers like Mach, Reynolds, Weber, etc.

Considering the eponymous noun is 'Mach number', is the following grammatically correct?

> His plane reached Mach 2.

Additionally is it appropriate to say:

> Almost no bears were found ejected in high Mach cases.

Comment: I don't think it's particularly a question of grammar; there are idiosyncratic conventions about how units are used. Your first sentence would be idiomatic, but I'm pretty sure the second wouldn't be.

Comment: Is *a high Mach case* a suitcase in the hold of a supersonic aircraft?

Comment: I want to know what the hell they were doing with bears?! First Google hit is "Turbulent Skin Friction at High Mach Numbers" which isn't easy on the bare.

Comment: @StuartF Do bears lose their hair at high Mach numbers?

Comment: Have you searched to see how people usually write such things? I'm sure that Google Books would have plenty of examples, for instance.

Comment: @WeatherVane Today I saw a story about a bear named Yogi ejected at supersonic speed from a B-58, to test the Hustler's escape capsule. So at least one.

Comment: @user888379 it was a suggested statement: saying *almost* none.

Comment: I wouldn't want to be the person that had to get a bear into the plane a second time.

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1.) Yes, this is correct. the "Mach number" refers to a certain *measurement of velocity* done in multiples of the speed of sound. For perhaps historical reasons (language doesn't evolve logically), we put the unit behind the number when we say "2 meters per second" but in front when we use the speed of sound as a reference like in "Mach 2".

So, "we are moving at Mach 2" means "our Mach number is 2".

Ad 2.) I am not sure what "bears" means in this sentence - perhaps very few bears are transported at super-sonic velocities and even fewer are ejected mid-flight - but even setting this aside  "in high Mach cases" sounds wrong to me. "Mach X" or the "Mach number X" refers to a *velocity*. Why not say "at high velocities" or "at high speeds" or, if we want to make clear which velocity ranges we mean, "velocities above/close to/in the range of/near ... Mach 1"?

For comparison, if a car does something at a high velocity we would talk about its "behavior at high-speed turns" or the police following it being in a "high-speed chase", but we wouldn't refer to any of those situations as a "high m/s [mph, km/h] case".

Comment: The thing is Mach number isn't a direct unit like meters per second, because it's a measurement of velocity relative to the speed of sound in that particular environment, which is influenced by ambient pressure, temperature and atmospheric composition (e.g. on Mars). Similarly a Reynolds number is dimensionless, but involves velocity, viscosity, and a specific length.